# Consolidates dates to weeks in Excel

Tags: excel, days

I would like to consolidates data in a table per day to a table per week.
I have an input table with all the days of the year in columns and all operators in rows. If an operator plans a holiday, we put a "H" on that day.

I'd like to have an output table with all weeks in rows and all operators in columns where I want to count the number of holidays an operator takes in a week.

Comment: How can I add a table in this comment box? Then I can show.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your data and Paste Special, Transpose into B1 of a new sheet. In A2 and copied down to suit:

```
=WEEKNUM(B2)
```

Select your data (entire columns would serve) and DATA, Outline, Subtotal, At each change in: `(ColumnA)`, Use function: `Count`, Add subtotal to: `tick each operator`, OK.